# jQuery AJAX MVC3 form data mismatch

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to send data as a model from an html form to a Controller method. I am, however, unsure of how the jQuery ajax post sends such information to the Controller. The actual error I get when I submit the form is:

> The resource could not be found... Requested URL: /OnCallSchedule

I know the address is correct, so I suspect that the data being passed does not match the model passed to the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getSchedule(DateModel dateMod)
{
    ...
    return Json(data);
}
```

The ajax code is:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        alert('@Url.Action("getSchedule")');
        var date = $('form').serialize();

        var jqxhr = $.post('@Url.Action("getSchedule")', date, function (data) {
            alert("success!");
        })
        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

        jqxhr.complete(function() { alert("second complete"); });
    });
});
```

The first alert statement, listing the path to the method, successfully triggers. After that, the error message pops up, and no other alerts appear.

It should be noted that I have tried this using just about every tactic, so I suspect that I am not sending the data correctly using the serialize() command. What am I doing wrong?

It's also likely that I am not performing the jqxhr actions correctly. The only place I could find understandable examples are in the jQuery documentation. I was originally using something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/OnCallSchedule/getSchedule',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#dataTable").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use Firebug, and I assume other debugging tools for other browsers, to view the request that's sent when you call `$.post()`, including the data that's sent along with it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The variable passed to the method is
    startDate=12%2F28%2F2011&endDate=12%2F28%2F2012
which I guess is the serialized format. It, however, doesn't match the model, which is two DateTime objects. How do I create a correctly typed variable?

Comment: Is your model not binding specifically to the date field on the model? If so this is known as a very tricky problem.

Comment: @TyroneMichael I'm not sure what you mean. I don't have a strong understanding of how HTML forms send data to Controller methods; I have successfully sent the data from my form to a HttpGet Index method (e.g. public ActionResult Index(DateModel dateMod)), which returns a view of the data I want, but I don't know if jQuery emulates that behavior with ajax.

Comment: Usually with ajax data is sent via json. Your server side model should automatically bind to the data that is being sent from the form. Can you debug and confirm if any of the form values are being bound to your Model (serverside)?

Comment: @TyroneMichael looking at the DOM tab in Firebug, the two model elements are present in 'Target' with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I am using the MVC style of forms (namely `@Html.BeginForm`), which was automatically calling out for a controller action. I was not successfully subverting this functionality, so the ajax code I wrote was pointless. I ended up doing away with the ajax function and `@Html.BeginForm` altogether, in favor of `@Ajax.BeginForm`. Specifically:

```
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("getSchedule",
                        "OnCallControl", 
                        new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod = "Post",
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        UpdateTargetId = "data"}))
{
    ...
}
```

I learned the hard way that MVC doesn't always play nice with functionality that its framework doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to `return false` from the form submit event handler.

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        ...
        return false;
    });
});
```